# What kind of ports are available to connect a Monitor?

Tags: display, cable, vga

I've an LG Widescreen M237WD TV/Monitor. Currently  I use it by connecting to my laptop via a a VGA cable. 
I plan to buy the [Dell XPS 9000](http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/desktops/desktop-studio-xps-9000/pd.aspx?refid=desktop-studio-xps-9000&s=dhs&cs=19) machine. How can I find out if I can connect it to my monitor using the VGA cable? Do new machines have VGA slots? If not, then can I buy an HDMI-HDMI cable to connect my machine to my monitor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most machines come built with a DVI slot these days (as long as you get a graphics card update).

You can do the following:

1. Grab a DVI->HDMI cable since they are very similar (one has sound, the other doesn't).
2. Grab a DVI->VGA adapter and use your current VGA cable to connect to your monitor (but now you just have an analog output :( ).
3. If the computer supports HDMI output, you can easily just do HDMI-HDMI.

My suggestion, just use HDMI because that machine states that it has a HDMI port. That way you can get great picture and audio!

Answer (score 1):

In the link provided, it shows that all video cards have DVI available, no cards have VGA. You can either get a DVI > VGA adapter, or get a DVI cable and use DVI if your monitor supports it.

Comment: Depends on the video card configured -- the machine I configured has a an nVidia GeForce GT200 and it features a DVI-I, HDMI, and a VGA.  The DVI-I can be adapted to HDMI or VGAm and the HDMI can be adapted to DVI.  You can only use two displays simultaneously though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the M237WD has a D-Sub VGA connector.  Most new video cards will have DVI of some typr.  I have used an adapter like this to connect a similar monitor to a new video card with DVI.  Some systems even ship with this type of adapter.

[DVI-VGA Adapter](http://www.startech.com/item/DVIVGAMF-DVI-to-VGA-Display-Adapter-MF.aspx)

Given that new info reports an HDMI port on the Monitor, select a video card that has HDMI and DVI and you can use a HDMI cable.  Failing that, there are HDMI-DVI adapters as mentioned.

Comment: the Monitor has a HDMI input slot.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what video card you configure with the machine -- the machine I configured has a an nVidia GeForce GT200 and it features a DVI-I, HDMI, and a VGA.

I believe the ATI option is the one picture-- which looks to have a DVI-I, HDMI, and a DisplayPort.

The DVI-I can be adapted to HDMI or VGA, the HDMI can be adapted to DVI, the DisplayPort can be adapted to HDMI and DVI.  Sometimes with an active adapter, the DisplayPort can send VGA signalling too.  You can only use two displays simultaneously though on the nVidia.  Not sure about ATI.